# Having a problem with my buttons not recognizing the number assigned to them

Tags: javascript

So I have been problem where I am trying to do a automatic state sales tax calculator . Where You click  your state button and you input your amount and At the bottom to shows how much the sales cost would be .

Where the buttons have a set percentage
But for some reason It will not recognize my input number or  my buttons .
Anyone know what I did wrong here?

```
       <button class="input1" data-ops="Alabama" data-num="4">Alabama</button>
        <button class="input1" data-ops="Alaska" data-num="0">Alaska</button>
        <button class="input1" data-ops="Arizona"   data-num="5.6">Arizona</button>
        <button class="input1" data-ops="Arkansas"   data-name="6.5">Arkansas</button>"`
```

`<label><textarea name="Salary" id="income" cols="30" rows="4" data-ops="input2"></textarea></label>`

```
    <button id="caluclate" data-ops="caluclate">Calculate</button>
    <div id="viewer" class="viewer">0</div>
```

`viewer.onclick  = function(){ viewer.innterHTML = input1 * input2; };`

```
viewer.innerHTML = "input1" * "input2";

caluclate.setAttribute("data-result", input1);
`




switch (input1) {
  case "Alabama":
    input1 = 4
      break;
      case "Alaska":
        input1 = 0
      break;`
`viewer.onclick  = function(){
   viewer.innterHTML = input1 * input2;
};

viewer.innerHTML = "input1" * "input2";`
```

My full code is on
https://github.com/BryanHankins/tax-rate-machine
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you multiplying strings?

Comment: Your code is really unclear. Show your actual code.

Comment: There're backticks allover the code, are they just in the post, or do those occur in the real code too? `viewer.innterHTML` doesn't probably do what you've intended ...

Comment: here is everything I have https://github.com/BryanHankins/tax-rate-machine


What I was trying to do was have it so when you click a state button . It inputs that variable and multiplies the percent . With the number you imputed.

Comment: It seems that the script is of beginner level. There are common things to correct initially. First you should use document.getElementByID or may be jquery to get to the button or any element ID from the Html. Example: for viewer: instead of viewer = "#viewer", you may write document.getElementByID("viewer").

Comment: Second thing is, you may wrap most of the code inside a click function, because the script will load with the page, but for what you want to achieve, the script should be within a button click function.